# How do I fix a drop column spelling error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Running Rails 6
I had a messages table I was no longer using and wanted to remove it. So I ran
rails g migration DropMessagesTable

and it appeared to run ok as the messages table disappeared from schema.

I then ran another removal, but of a column only this time:
rails g migration RemoveEnd_timeFromAudtions end_time:datetime

and I got this error:

```
 rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RemoveEndTimeFromAudtions
Did you mean?  RemoveEndTimeFromAuditions
/Users/xxxx/Documents/hosting/rct21/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xxxx/Documents/hosting/rct21/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
NameError: uninitialized constant RemoveEndTimeFromAudtions
Did you mean?  RemoveEndTimeFromAuditions
/Users/xxxx/Documents/hosting/rct21/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xxxx/Documents/hosting/rct21/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

As you can see I misspelled "audition" as "audtions"
So I tried rails db:rollback and that did not work.

Any ideas to fix?

Comment: i think the needed command does not `rollback` since the last (misspelled) migration is not successful, right ? you could use `rails destroy migration RemoveEnd_timeFromAudtions end_time:datetime`  (or just delete the last migration file by hand), create new one (correct name) then run `rails db:migrate` again.

Comment: It looks like the migration file-name is not matching with the class name in that file. If your class-name is `RemoveAbcColumnFromDef`, your file name should be `timestamp_remove_abc_column_from_def.rb`. You can fix the naming issue in the same file and commit it. No need of deleting it and creating a new file.

Answer (score 0):

it's looks like you did not write de down methods in your migration.

you can rollback by yourself in the database, and make you migration files right, then run it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was from Lam Phan. I'm not sure how you credit someone when their answer isn't next to the check mark:

rails destroy migration RemoveEnd_timeFromAudtions end_time:datetime